# In F#, what does error of type mismatch between "Expecting" and "Given" mean?

Tags: f#, elmish-wpf

I am receiving the following error when using the Binding.subModelSelectedItem():

```
FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a 'string -> Binding<(Model * 'a), b>' 
but given a
  'string -> Binding<Model,Msg>'.
The type 'Model * 'a' does not match the type 'Model'
```

From the following F# code:

```
type Msg =
        | SetAppointmentKey  of int option
```

Then, in the bindings:

```
 "SelectedAppointmentKey" |> Binding.subModelSelectedItem("AppointmentKeys", (fun m -> m.SelectedAppointmentKey), SetAppointmentKey)
```

I do not understand the error message. What does the error message mean?  "Expecting" from who? "Given" from what?

Sorry for my ignorance here, but nothing this newbie has tried has fixed this.

Thank you for any help.

TIA

Comment: Essentially cross posted to https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/issues/281

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where the specific error is in your code, but I can try to help you understand what the error message says. A simple example to illustrate the same error:

```
let foo (f:int -> int) = ()
let bar x = ""
foo bar
```

This does not work, because `foo` expects a function `int -> int`, but `bar` returns a `string`. You get:

> error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a `int -> int` but given a
> `int -> string`
> The type `int` does not match the type `string`

The error message tells you that the function you're using as an argument has a wrong type. It tells you the two types and also a part of it where it goes wrong (here, the return types do not match).

Looking at your error message:

> FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a `string -> Binding<(Model * 'a), 'b>`
> but given a
> `string -> Binding<Model,Msg>`.
> The type `Model * 'a` does not match the type `Model`

It seems that you are creating a function somewhere that takes a string and returns a `Binding`. This function is expected to return a `Binding` with `Model` as the first type parameter, but your code returns a tuple formed by `Model` and some other thing.

Something like this can easily happen if you have `fun x -> ..., something` in your code, perhaps in a place where you wanted `(fun x -> ...), something`. You would get a similar error if you wrote, e.g.:

```
let foo (f:int -> int) = ()
let bar = fun x -> 0, 1 
foo bar
```

Comment: Isn't the function expected to return a Binding with the first parameter being the tuple of Model * 'a  ?   Thanks.